# Install scrapy on mac successful, but run error

Tags: python, macos, scrapy

```
gaoyaqiu:git gaoyaqiu$ scrapy 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File /usr/local/bin/scrapy, line 7, in <module>
      from scrapy.cmdline import execute
  File /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py, line 9, in <module>
      from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
  File /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py, line 7, in <module>
      from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
  File /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/reactor.py, line 38, in <module>
      from twisted.internet import default
  File /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/default.py, line 56, in <module>
      install = _getInstallFunction(platform)
  File /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/default.py, line 50, in _getInstallFunction
      from twisted.internet.selectreactor import install
  File /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/selectreactor.py, line 18, in <module>
      from twisted.internet import posixbase
  File /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py, line 18, in <module>
      from twisted.internet import error, udp, tcp
  File /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py, line 28, in <module>
      from twisted.internet._newtls import (
  File /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_newtls.py, line 21,  in <module>
      from twisted.protocols.tls import TLSMemoryBIOFactory, TLSMemoryBIOProtocol
  File /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py, line 63, in  <module>
      from twisted.internet._sslverify import _setAcceptableProtocols
  File /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py, line 38, in <module>
      TLSVersion.TLSv1_1: SSL.OP_NO_TLSv1_1,
AttributeError: module object has no attribute OP_NO_TLSv1_1
```

Comment: Please format your code, it is unreadable.

Comment: Provide More Information, How you installed it Via Pip or easy_install, is any other Python version also installed in the existing Machine ?

Comment: perhaps you don't have the right version of `twisted` installed?

Comment: @RahulSharma I installed by PIP，There are python3.5 and 2.7 versions on the computer.

Comment: fixed indentation of the text to match what is actually produced by the software

Answer (score 4):

I came across with same issue.

The following thread helped.

```
pip install Twisted==16.4.1
```

> If you need sudo access then add it to your command.

https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2473

Answer (score 3):

actually it is solved by:

```
 pip install pyopenssl --upgrade
```

from the link: [scrapy: 'module' object has no attribute 'OP_SINGLE_ECDH_USE'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573038/scrapy-module-object-has-no-attribute-op-single-ecdh-use)

Comment: This answer worked for me, and it looks to me like the true solution.