# scrapy: 'module' object has no attribute 'OP_SINGLE_ECDH_USE'

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new in scrapy, I create a sample project in scrapy and run the project. I got an error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OP_SINGLE_ECDH_USE'
```

Code:

```
import scrapy
class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.grocerygateway.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove `Thanks in advance` and code will work.

Comment: Umair, sorry. 'thanks in advance' is not in code. Its due to the problem of question posting

Comment: Please provide the full traceback (the line with the error you got + the precending lines) from your console

Comment: Also, the full spider.

Comment: And also the output of `scrapy version -v` to see your version of Scrapy, Twisted, OpenSSL etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had a similar error, found that pyopenssl was not installed correctly

Simply did

> sudo apt-get install libssl-dev

then

> pip install pyopenssl --upgrade

scrapy scraped again

linux mint 18.1

Comment: solved the issue on Ubuntu 16.04 with Scrapy 1.3.3, thanks!