# scrapy Error module object has no attribute 'OP_SINGLE_ECDH_USE'

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

while running scrapy I am getting the following error. 
Could someone please let me know which version of scrapy is more stable?

I have referred to the following page and no help so opened a new thread.

[scrapy: 'module' object has no attribute 'OP_SINGLE_ECDH_USE'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573038/scrapy-module-object-has-no-attribute-op-single-ecdh-use)

**Error:**

```
    self._options |= SSL.OP_SINGLE_DH_USE | SSL.OP_SINGLE_ECDH_USE
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OP_SINGLE_ECDH_USE'
2017-06-09 10:05:54 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://www.yellowpages.com.au/search/listings?clue=debt+collection+services&eventType=pagination&locationClue=Australia&pageNumber=4&referredBy=www.yellowpages.com.au>
```

**pip freeze:**

```
asn1crypto==0.22.0
attrs==17.2.0
Automat==0.6.0
cffi==1.10.0
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==1.9
cssselect==1.0.1
enum34==1.1.6
idna==2.5
incremental==17.5.0
ipaddress==1.0.18
lxml==3.8.0
parsel==1.2.0
pkg-resources==0.0.0
pyasn1==0.2.3
pyasn1-modules==0.0.9
pycparser==2.17
PyDispatcher==2.0.5
pyOpenSSL==17.0.0
queuelib==1.4.2
Scrapy==1.4.0
service-identity==17.0.0
six==1.10.0
Twisted==17.1.0
w3lib==1.17.0
zope.interface==4.4.1
```

There is nothing wrong with the spider code, but I am using scrapy after few months so not sure if something has changed.

```
Class YellowSpider(Spider):
    name = "yellowpages"
    allowed_domains = ["www.yellowpages.com.au"]
    start_urls = []

    for i in range(1,5):
        start_urls.append("https://www.yellowpages.com.au/search/listings?clue=debt+collection+services&eventType"
                          "=pagination&locationClue=Australia&pageNumber=%s&referredBy=www.yellowpages.com.au"
                          % i)

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = YellowpagesItem()
        companies = hxs.select("//*[@class='cell in-area-cell middle-cell']")

        for comapny in companies:
            name = hxs.select("//a[@class='listing-name']/text()").extract()

            print name
```

Comment: Looking at similar threads, usually there is a file path named before the part where you started to copy your error message. See for example [this issue](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2473) on github, where the path clearly shows something is happening within the Twisted package. Maybe review that path, consider upgrading/downgrading the package.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks, Casper.
moving **twisted to 16.4.1** resolved the issue. Posting the answer in case if someone faces the similar issue.